# rotate 2d vector 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: c++

Hi I have a function that is supposed to rotate a 2d vector that holds pixel values from a pgm file.

```
void pgm_cw( vector <IVec> &p )
{
    vector <IVec> temp;     // temporary vector of vectors of ints
    int count = 0;         // count variable
    int count2 = 0;       // 2nd count variable

    temp.resize( p.size() );
    for( count = 0; count < p.size(); count++ )
    {
        temp[count].resize( p[count].size() );
        for( count2 = 0; count2 < temp[count].size(); count2++ )
        {
            temp[count][count2] = p[count][count2];
        }
    }
    for( count = 0; count < temp.size(); count++ )
    {
        for( count2 = 0; count2 < temp[count].size(); count2++ )
        {
            temp[count][count2] = temp[count][temp[count].size()-count2-1];
                    // set temp vector to p with 90 degree rotation
        }
    }
    p = temp;       // set p equal to temp
}
```

The output is not correct. any ideas on how to fix it? thanks

Comment: In future questions, you might want to prepare an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not containing classes like `IVec` that need to be guessed. Also, for short programs that don't work, you might want to add printouts along the stages of the program, indicating what they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach for your problem.

```
void pgm_cw( vector <IVec> &temp )
{

    int N = temp.size();

    for (int x = 0; x < N / 2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = x; y < N-x-1; y++)
        {
            // store current cell in temp variable
            int tmp = temp[x][y];

            // move values from right to top
            temp[x][y] = temp[y][N-1-x];

            // move values from bottom to right
            temp[y][N-1-x] = temp[N-1-x][N-1-y];

            // move values from left to bottom
            temp[N-1-x][N-1-y] = temp[N-1-y][x];

            // assign temp to left
            temp[N-1-y][x] = tmp;
        }
    }
    //std::swap(p,temp);
    //p = temp;       // set p equal to temp
}
```

[Inplace rotate square matrix by 90 degrees](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/)

Comment: Note that in this case, you wont need the `std::swap(p,temp)`. This answer is more efficient than mine, since it doesnt require allocating an entire additional array, which could be expensive depending on how large the array you're trying to rotate is.

Comment: Also, the question asks "rotate 2d vector 90 degrees clockwise", but the algorithm you have at the moment rotates counter-clockwise. Sorry to be a pest! :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually doing a mirror transformation about the vertical center. Also, you're looping through a vector and then re-assigning back to that vector. This means you're going to be filling the vector with values that dont reflect your original passed vector at some point in the second for-loop.

For an algorithm that is generic to the number of pixels in x,y here is something:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IVec;

void pgm_cw( std::vector<IVec> &p )
{
    // Need to allocate an array to store the transform
    std::vector<IVec> temp(p[0].size(), IVec(p.size()));

    int count = 0;        // count variable
    int count2 = 0;      // 2nd count variable

    for( count = 0; count < p.size(); count++ )
    {
        for( count2 = 0; count2 < p[0].size(); count2++ )
        {
            // Clockwise rotation
            temp[count2][temp[0].size()-count-1] = p[count][count2];
            // Counter-clockwise rotation
            //temp[temp.size()-count2-1][count] = p[count][count2];
        }
    }

    p = temp;       // set p equal to temp
}
```

I've included an explicit `typedef` so that I could test it out. Here's a quick test:

```
BEFORE:
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9 10 11 12
AFTER:
  9  5  1
 10  6  2
 11  7  3
 12  8  4
```

Hopefully that helps a bit for the asymmetric array case.

Comment: that kind of made the output worse.It compiled but gave me an error when i ran it that said invalid next isze

Comment: Are you trying to do a square array, or are your x,y pixel sizes different?

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for a 2D array where the sizes in the two dimensions are not equal. Also, I added an example showing that it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really over complicating it in my head. I got it working